# .sendKeys() method doesn't work when i tried to put value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I want to send value to "search" input but sendKeys() method doesn't work. I checked the "xpath" path manually, added the clear() method before putting values but nothing changed. Also added WebdriverWait.
There is method:

```
 public Seminar searchSeminarByName(String seminarName){
      WebElement searchInp = driver.findElement(searchInput);
      if (searchInp == null){
          log.error("Can not find element by {}", searchInput);
      }else{
          log.info("Founded element ex {}", searchInp);
          log.info("Founded element {}", searchInp.getTagName());
      }

      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(searchInp));
      searchInp.click();
      searchInp.sendKeys(seminarName);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(searchInp, seminarName));
      searchInp.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

      WebElement seminarId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[1]"));
      WebElement seminarNametd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]"));
      WebElement seminarStatus =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[4]"));

      return new Seminar(Long.parseLong(seminarId.getText()), seminarNametd.getText(),seminarStatus.getText());
  }
```

This method sends value on "Search" input and returns found info from the page.
Check the info in another class by using the method:

```
@Test
    public void searchFieldCheck(){
        Seminar seminar = seminarPage.searchSeminarByName(groupName);
        Assert.assertEquals(groupName, seminar.getName());
    }
```

The logs to run test:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355}) on port 11594
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1612355832.736][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 88.
февр. 03, 2021 2:37:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
2021-02-03 14:37:22.387 [main] INFO  SeminarPage - Founded element ex [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (3e6dd669a7b7ad62f24b6dd150da861b)] -> xpath: //input/parent::div/*]
2021-02-03 14:37:22.394 [main] INFO  SeminarPage - Founded element input

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element ([[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (3e6dd669a7b7ad62f24b6dd150da861b)] -> xpath: //input/parent::div/*]) to be selected (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-PS8FAB8', ip: '172.18.76.97', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '14.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 88.0.4324.104, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:41163}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 3e6dd669a7b7ad62f24b6dd150da861b

    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at SeminarPage.searchSeminarByName(SeminarPage.java:48)
    at SeminarPageTest.searchFieldCheck(SeminarPageTest.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

**Update**

The issue was too fast work of Selenium added to code Thread.sleep(500);
Code(used lombok):

```
@SneakyThrows
  public Seminar searchSeminarByName(String seminarName){
      WebElement searchInp = driver.findElement(searchInput);
      if (searchInp == null){
          log.error("Can not find element by {}", searchInput);
      }else{
          log.info("Founded element ex {}", searchInp);
          log.info("Founded element {}", searchInp.getTagName());
      }

      //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
      //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(searchInp));
      searchInp.click();
      Thread.sleep(500); //Required waite, because "sendKeys" is ignored for some time after render.
      //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(searchInp));
      searchInp.sendKeys(seminarName);
      //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(searchInp, seminarName));
      Thread.sleep(500);
      searchInp.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
      Thread.sleep(700);
      WebElement seminarId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[1]"));
      WebElement seminarNametd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]"));
      WebElement seminarStatus =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[4]"));

      return new Seminar(Long.parseLong(seminarId.getText()), seminarNametd.getText(),seminarStatus.getText());
  }
```

The test is passed:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96 (68dba2d8a0b149a1d3afac56fa74648032bcf46b-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#1784}) on port 19322
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
февр. 03, 2021 9:27:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
2021-02-03 21:27:06.999 [main] INFO  SeminarPage - Founded element ex [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (50d08a5eaebefd27100eb7990b7149f8)] -> xpath: //input/parent::div/*]
2021-02-03 21:27:07.006 [main] INFO  SeminarPage - Founded element input
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(searchInp));
```

According to your log, `searchInp` is not a clickable element. Inspect your page and maybe change this expected condition to "element present".  For example:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
```

Where `locator` is one of multiple localization strategies implemented in the `org.openqa.selenium.By` class:

1. `className(String className)`
2. `cssSelector(String selectorName)`
3. `id(String id)`
4. `linkText(String linkText)`
5. `name(String name)`
6. `partialLinkText(String partialLinkText)`
7. `tagName(String tagName)`
8. `xpath(String xpath)`

The most powerful in my opinion is by XPath. It is also the most complicated. For your case, you could do something like `By locator = By.xpath("some xpath string here");` and then pass that locator to `ExpectedConditions`.

I also suggest you read on web driver `click` method so that you could have a better understanding under what conditions and what type of elements this function will work on.

**UPDATE**:

Without having intimate knowledge of the structure of the page, is very hard to figure out why `sendKeys` will not work. A potential problem is that the field you need to send keystrokes to is in an iframe. If this is the case, you must tell the web driver to switch to the iframe and then send they keystrokes to the field. Once you are done, you need to switch back from the iframe to the main window (frame). A quick search on the web for "selenium switch to iframe" should point you in the right direction **IF THIS IS THE ISSUE**.

Comment: Thanks! Commented whole "wait". Test is gone but .sendKeys doesn't send values  
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
февр. 03, 2021 5:11:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
2021-02-03 17:11:43.704 [main] INFO  SeminarPage - Founded element ex [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (e1cadfaf76c3b15a4d6c42dd227f997e)] -> xpath: //input/parent::div/*]
2021-02-03 17:11:43.709 [main] INFO  SeminarPage - Founded element input               org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Gtest
Actual   :DSem31
<Click to see difference>

Comment: @ФредерикГуральник can you update the ticket with the portion of the DOM with the element you need to interact with?

Comment: I had found a solution how to avoid the issue with sendKeys(), added it to the ticket. May you know any selenium method to make a smart wait before action? The issue with loading the website selenium works too fast

Comment: There are plenty of `ExpectedConditions` that you should use. It is STRONGLY recommended to avoid `Thread.sleep` do to this. I mentioned one on my post.

Comment: @ФредерикГуральник the good news is that it means that you don't have an `iframe` to worry about this time. BUT, it is something you need to be painfully aware for the future.